# ejabberd configuration: domain vs. server/hosts (and their SSL certificates)

Tags: ssl, configuration, ejabberd

In [documentation basics](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/basic/), we find the following examples for configuration of the `hosts` [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) element:

```
Serving one domain:

hosts: [example.org]

Serving three domains:

hosts:
   - example.net
   - example.com
   - jabber.somesite.org
```

(The above are of course just two different ways of writing a YAML "list", once using the bracket notation, once using the indent-with-hypen notation).

A bit later, we see:

```
## This ejabberd server has three vhosts:
hosts:
  - one.example.org
  - two.example.org
  - three.example.org
```

This is confusing.

As I understand, an XMPP *domain* (e.g. `example.com`) can be serviced by several *servers* or *hosts* (e.g. `one.example.com`, `two.example.com`, `three.example.com`).

The configuration seems to commingle XMPP domain and server.

- Is the XMPP domain deduced from the servername? For example, if I enter `one.example.org`, is the XMPP domain `example.org` - or is it `one.example.org`?
- If I just give the domain name under `hosts`, do I have to map the domain name to an actual IP endpoint in DNS?

Additionally, an SSL certificate will be requested via ACME

- Will this be a certificate for the XMPP domain (`example.com`) or for the server (`one.example.com`) or will it be a wildcard certificate?
- Will the ACME service (of Letsencrypt, say) give me a certificate for `example.org` if I already *have* a certificate for the webserver of `example.org`?

Answer (score 0):

You can even have:

```
hosts:
 - example.net
 - example.com
 - jabber.somesite.org
 - one.example.org
 - two.example.org
 - three.example.org
 - 11.22.33.44
```

This sets 7 different XMPP vhosts, each one with their specific accounts, MUC service, PubSub service...

Clients can authenticate to accounts like jon@example.net, tim@two.example.org, bot7@11.22.33.44, ...

It is your duty, as system administrator, to setup DNS so the XMPP clients know the IP address where ejabberd is listening for them. Except for the 11.22.33.44 IP address, which obviously the clients already know where to connect to.

Notice that you can have ejabberd serving one.example.org, and same or different XMPP server, in same or different machine, serving eleven.example.org